# mongodb Query result - storing the value in jsonObject

Tags: java, json, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I am executing a query in mongodb which gives the following result :

```
    {
        "_id" : "180",
        "total" : 1
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "181",
        "total" : 1
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "182",
        "total" : 29
    }
```

Here i am passing the upper limit of **_id** as 186 and lower limit as 180.

So, the query searches for the **_id** and passes the value.

But i want to store the result as follows. The missing **_id** should store 0.

```
{
    "_id" : "180",
    "total" : 1
}, 
{
    "_id" : "181",
    "total" : 1
}, 
{
    "_id" : "182",
    "total" : 29
},
{
    "_id" : "183",
    "total" : 0
},
{
    "_id" : "184",
    "total" : 0
},
{
    "_id" : "185",
    "total" : 0
},
{
    "_id" : "186",
    "total" : 0
}
```

I am trying to insert the values after getting the result in Java in following manner.

dayST and daySTP is upper and lower limit of **_id**.

```
output = table.aggregate( pipeline );
   for ( final DBObject res : output.results() ) 
      {
        for (;dayST<daySTP;dayST++)
            {
             int _id1 = Integer.parseInt(res.get("_id").toString());
                if(dayST == _id1)
                 {
                   data.add( new Gson().fromJson( res.toString(), JsonObject.class ) );


                 }
                else
                {       
                final JsonObject dataForNoResults = new JsonObject();
                dataForNoResults.addProperty( "_id", dayST );
                dataForNoResults.addProperty( "totalcount", 0 );
                data.add( dataForNoResults );

                }

             }


       }
```

But,It gives the following output :

```
 {"_id":"180","totalcount":1},
 {"_id":181,"totalcount":0},
 {"_id":182,"totalcount":0},
 {"_id":183,"totalcount":0},
 {"_id":184,"totalcount":0},
 {"_id":185,"totalcount":0},
 {"_id":186,"totalcount":0}
```

I know the logic in my loops are not correct.Can anyone please point it out ?

Edit:
I solved it using this :

```
ArrayList<Integer> ar = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> br = new ArrayList<Integer>();

output = table.aggregate( pipeline );
  for ( final DBObject res : output.results() ) 
     {
      data.add( new Gson().fromJson( res.toString(), JsonObject.class ) );
      ar.add(Integer.parseInt(res.get("_id").toString()));                              
       }
                    while(dayST<daySTP)
                 { 
                        if(!ar.contains(dayST)){
                            br.add(dayST);}
                        dayST++;
                 }
                    for(int i = 0;i< br.size();i++)
                    {
                        final JsonObject dataForNoResults = new JsonObject();
                        dataForNoResults.addProperty( "_id", br.get(i) );
                        dataForNoResults.addProperty( "totalcount", 0 );
                        data.add( dataForNoResults );
                    }
```

**Is there any better solution ?**

Answer (score -2):

It's a looping issue.

```
while (dayST<daySTP)
{
    for ( final DBObject res : output.results() ) 
    {
        if(dayST == _id1)
        {
            data.add( new Gson().fromJson( res.toString(), JsonObject.class ) );
        }
        else
        {       
           JsonObject dataForNoResults = new JsonObject();
           dataForNoResults.addProperty( "_id", dayST );
           dataForNoResults.addProperty( "totalcount", 0 );
           data.add( dataForNoResults );
        } 
        dayST++; 
    }
}
```

Comment: {"_id":"180","totalcount":1},{"_id":"181","totalcount":1},{"_id":"182","totalcount":29},{"_id":183,"totalcount":0},{"_id":184,"totalcount":0},{"_id":185,"totalcount":0},{"_id":186,"totalcount":0},{"_id":187,"totalcount":0},{"_id":188,"totalcount":0},{"_id":189,"totalcount":0}

Comment: gives this output when _id is set as 180 and 186

Comment: Folks, I don't understand why down vote ?  <br> In the above solution we are getting expected output those additional value 187,188 and 189 how would what's the value for daySTP, assumption was daySTP value to be 186. <br> Before voting down, it would be nice if reason is specified.